# Nginx - Cloud Server with 2 Nginx reverse proxies server

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, nginx

I have a cloud server ubuntu 18.04, I got a back-end API (**.NET Core**) and a front-end **Angular** application (both of app were deployed inside docker container). The back-end API first upload so I config a nginx proxy on **cloud server**. And then when I dockerize Angular app, but all examples out there are dockerized with nginx. Whether It can dockerize angular app standalone without nginx?.

Therefore now, the cloud server have two nginx reverse proxies. One on server, one inside Angular container @@

**My thinking**

1. Should I public IP address to outside the world, all requests will forward directly to Angular container IP.
2. If I don't public IP of the angular container (setup firewall). A request have to get through 2 nginx proxies (because angular app now is deployed along with nginx). How can I dockerize angular app without nginx?
3. Should I deploy nginx along with container for both of back-end and front-end?
4. One cloud server should be one nginx for an application. Then I split two back-end and front-end, each  is deployed separated cloud server.

Comment: If you want to dockerize your angular app, you need to have a web server to host the compiled files (like nginx, nodejs, apache, or webpack). During development, you were likely using the built in webpack server, and that server is not recommended or safe for production. First you will need to decide what server you will use to host the output distribution files, then you will need to set up a docker service for it with the output of the angular build.

Comment: Because angular app must to be hosted, therefore I did dockerize angular on nginx. But there a question I'm confused that I already configured nginx on cloud server. So should I forward a request directly to angular container and Backend container also dockerize with nginx (Cloud server will no longer have nginx proxy). Am I right?

Comment: You could configure your angular nginx to reverse proxy to your backend, then you wouldn't need to use a second  nginx for the backend. Or you can put the build output in a docker volume and connect it to your backend nginx container for hosting.

Comment: Thanks @MrDick47, I will try to build angular app to docker volume, and use nginx on *Cloud Server* to connect to serve compiled files for front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion in the comment section, I thought I would share my angular-app Dockerfile and Docker compose config files for reference:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
ARG mode=prod
ENV mode=$mode

RUN apk --no-cache add \
tzdata \
git \
python \
g++ \
make

ENV TZ=${TZ:-America/Chicago}
RUN echo "$TZ" > /etc/timezone && date

EXPOSE 4200
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

#To take advantage of docker's caching, first only copy the package.json and
# package-lock.json, then run npm install
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

#This way the node_modules will be stored in an image build stage cache,
# which means it won't need to reinstall node_modules every build, but will
# reinstall them if either the package.json or package-lock.json file changes.

COPY *.js* ./
COPY src ./src

RUN [[ -z $mode ]] && npm run build || npm run build:$mode
```

docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  express-api:
    container_name: express-api
    build: ./express-api
    user: ${DOCKER_USER:-0:0}
    expose:
      - "3000"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Chicago
    volumes:
      - ./express-api/ssl-certs/:/home/node/ssl-certs:ro

  angular-app:
    container_name: angular-app
    build:  ./angular-app
    user: ${DOCKER_USER:-0:0}
    expose:
      - "4200"
    restart: "on-failure"
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Chicago
    volumes:
      - app_dist:/home/node/dist
      - ./angular-app/ssl-certs/:/home/node/ssl-certs:ro

  angular-docs:
    container_name: angular-docs
    build:
      context: ./angular-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-docs
    user: ${DOCKER_USER:-0:0}
    expose:
      - "8080"
    restart: "on-failure"
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Chicago

  nginx-server:
    container_name: nginx-server
    build: ./nginx-server
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    environment:
      - TZ=America/Chicago
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-server/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx-server/ssl-certs/:/etc/nginx/ssl-certs:ro
      - app_dist:/var/www:ro

volumes:
  app_dist:
```

and I merge that compose file with this one for production:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  express-api:
    env_file: prod.env

  angular-app:
    build:
      args:
        mode: "prod"
    env_file: prod.env

  nginx-server:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    env_file: prod.env
```

and inside my angular package json I have these scripts:

```
"build": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",
"build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
```

I removed some lines out of these before posting but they should help get you started. This setup uses one container to build the angular-app distribution files and stores it in a volume that is shared with the nginx container which serves the files and has a reverse proxy for the express-api backend.

The DOCKER_USER env variable is set by a bash script beforehand with this:

`export DOCKER_USER="${USERID:-1000}:${USERGID:-1000}"`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your helps. I love your enthusiasm. I'm just begin to learn Docker to deploy. So that, at RUN command *RUN [[ -z $mode ]]* what does it mean?.

Comment: Sorry I was late to respond to this, it is a bash command that can basically be read like this:
`if(!$mode) npm run build;`
`else npm run build:$mode;`